# Android - add dynamically fragments to activity

Tags: android

I have an activity,and i want to add dynamically my fragments depending on the orientation, so i did as following:
**Calendrier.java**

```
package com.thinline.dm21.calendrier;

public class Calendrier extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calendrier_main);
    //ajouter les fragments Planifications et Calendrier mensuel 
    ajouterFragments();       
}

public void ajouterFragments(){
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 1){

    }
    else if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 2){
        ft.add(R.id.calendrier_planifictions, new Planifications());
        ft.add(R.id.calendrier_calendrierhebdomadaire, new CalendrierHebdomadaire());
    }

    ft.commit();
}
}
```

this is my **layout/calendrier_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/calendrier_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/calendrier_planifictions"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/calendrier_calendrierhebdomadaire"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" >
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and my **layout-port/calendrier.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/calendrier_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/calendrier_planifictions"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/calendrier_calendrierhebdomadaire"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" >
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

my problem is:

- When i start my application in portrait mode, a i get a black screen and when i rotate it, i get my two others fragments which is good, but when i rotate it again (to portrait) i still have my fragments instead of my black screen, normally it should display a black screen because both onCreate and onDestroy are excuted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android keeps fragments after rotation changes, so in portrait mode you need to check if fragments are added and if so, you need to remove them. Your code should be similar to following example:

```
private static final String PLANIFICATIONS_FRAG_TAG = "PLANIFICATIONS_FRAG_TAG";
private static final String CALENDAR_FRAG_TAG = "CALENDAR_FRAG_TAG"; 

public void ajouterFragments(){
    Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    Planifications planificationsFrag = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(PLANIFICATIONS_FRAG_TAG);
    CalendrierHebdomadaire calendarFrag = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(CALENDAR_FRAG_TAG);

    if (configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        if (planificationsFrag != null) 
            ft.remove(fragment);
        if (calendarFrag != null) 
            ft.remove(calendarFrag);
     }
     else if (configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
         if (planificationsFrag == null) 
            ft.add(R.id.calendrier_planifictions, new Planifications(), PLANIFICATIONS_FRAG_TAG);
         if (calendarFrag == null) 
             ft.add(R.id.calendrier_calendrierhebdomadaire, new CalendrierHebdomadaire(), CALENDAR_FRAG_TAG);
     }

    ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: I'am glad it helped :). Btw you should accept the answer, if was useful or vote up.

Answer (score 0):

Android keeps the fragments added to your activity when you rotate. You need to flag if you already added the fragments and remove them on activity create.

Comment: could you give me more technical details ?